# Search results in multi page - page numbers should be shown on top & bottom

Tags: feature-request, search, pagination

Search results exceeding more than one page are shown in multi pages as shown below

[image]

But currently this is showing only at the bottom of the page. If user scroll from bottom to top this bar will not be there and user again has to scroll to the bottom of the page to switch to another page.

Thus the page number also displayed at the top.

Comment: That's pretty uncommon design. Usually user will want to read first then go to different page only if he didn't find what he's looking for in the current page. Also, you can always narrow the search down (by adding more keywords or relevant tags) to have better results with less pages.

Comment: No you can find at-least **Go to Top** link in some websites also here there is no question of narrowing the results. This is helpful when user lists all low quality questions for corrections and he wish to read all these questions from bottom to top.

Comment: Still don't think it's very needed. Don't get me wrong, it's totally fine to request this just saying my own personal opinion about it.